# Send live json data to Swift IOS app from Sonos callbackURL for subscribed events

Tags: swift, nsnotificationcenter, pusher, urlsession, sonos

I am currently building a Sonos IOS app with Swift to include a Today Widget. The app will control and show metadata for Sonos players. I have all the code working and URLsessions for POST and GET requests but I'm having difficulty updating the play state or metadata when a change is made on another app or on the physical speaker. For example, if I skip forward via my app I use a POST request to update the metadata, that works perfectly.  If I skip forward on the native Sonos app my app's metadata will not update.

I understand what I have to do is subscribe to the Sonos namespace and set up a callback URL and register it with Sonos (Which I have done). I have subscribed to the playbackmetadata namespace and I am using https://webhook.site for testing. I get the 200 ok response and I can see the JSON data live in the body which is updated instantly when a track is skipped via any app or player.

This is exactly what I need, but I've no idea how to get it back to my app.

I use the following code to subscribe to the namespace. This works to subscribe.

```
//Subscribe
let requestStr = "https://api.ws.sonos.com/control/api/v1/groups/\(currentRoom)/playbackMetadata/subscription"
    apiManager.postToSonos(requestStr: requestStr)

//apiManager
func postToSonos(requestStr: String) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: requestStr)!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.setValue("Bearer \(access_token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let task = sessionSonos.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("Post Error")
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
            return
        }

        let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
            print(responseJSON)
            print("responseJSON")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

My problem is getting the updated JSON back into my app. I have also set up an AWS-Lambda server as a callbackURL. I don't really know what I am doing with this either but I can get the live JSON updated to here too. I am thinking of using the pusher to send a silent notification back. I have set up the account with pusher but no idea how to send the correct data back to my app and making sure that the correct data goes back to each end-user. Maybe there is some other way to do this that I am missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'silent' Push notification to get it back to your app.

Comment: Thanks ControlAV. I read somewhere that these are low priority and will not always work in the background but I’ll play around with it and see how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

I do use Pusher to send the Sonos callback data to my application (in my case, a TVOS app). To handle the json data on your web site, you have to create a web app. I created a Python web app using the Flask framework and the web app is hosted on Heroku. In the web app, I use the Python client library that Pusher has made available on Github to push the Sonos data back to my TVOS app.